# Proof of a property regarding weak-star topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, topological-vector-spaces

I am reading a book in which a theorem is only proven analogously in the situation of weak topology. The proof does not seem to work in the case of weak$^{*}$ topology.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. By definition, the weak$^{*}$ topology of $X^{*}$ is generated by the collection of seminorms $\{q_x : x \in X\}$, where $q_x (f) = |f(x)|$.

A theorem says that

> A linear functional on $X^{*}$ is weak$^{*}$ continuous if and only if it belongs to $K= \iota(X)$, with the embedding $\iota:X \rightarrow X^{**}$ defined by $(\iota(x))(f)= f(x)$.

The "if" direction is easy. For the "only if" direction, by standard results, there exist $x_1 , \ldots, x_n \in X$ and $\alpha >0$ such that 
$$ |g(f) | \leq \alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n} q_{x_i} (f) := \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)|, \quad \quad \forall f \in X^{*}.$$

This time, unlike in the case of weak topology, the kernel argument fails. How can we show that $g= \iota (x)$, for some $x \in X$?

Comment: What is your working definition of the weak$*$ topology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the idea.

Suppose there are functionals $g_1,...,g_n$ and $g$ such that $\cap_k \ker g_k \subset g$ then we can write
$g = \sum_k \eta_k g_k $ for some $\eta_k$.

To see this, let $\phi:X \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be defined by $\phi(x) = (g_1(x),...,g_n(x))$ and note that
$\phi(x) = \phi(y) $ means that $g(x) = g(y)$. In particular, if we define
the equivalence $x \sim y$ **iff** $\phi(x-y) = 0$, then we see that
$\tilde{\phi} : X / \sim \, \to \mathbb{C}^n$ defined by
$\tilde{\phi} ([x]) = \phi(x)$ is well defined and  an isomorphism and
$\tilde{g} ([x]) = g(x)$ is well defined.
Let $h: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ be $h = \tilde{g}\circ \tilde{\phi}^{-1}$,we see that $h$ is linear, hence $h(z) = \eta^T z$ for
some $\eta$, and so $g(x) = \tilde{g}([x])  = (h \circ \tilde{\phi})([x])=
(h \circ \phi)(x) = \sum_k \eta_k g_k(x)$, or, in other words,
$g = \sum_k \eta_k g_k$.

Now note that the last inequality in the question implies a containment of the intersection of kernels and hence we can write $g = \sum_k \alpha_k \iota(x_k)$ for 
some $\alpha_k$.

Comment: But I'm not sure whether for each $k$, $q_{x_k}$ is in $K$ or not.....
By definition, $q_s (f) = |f(s)| = |(\iota(s))(f)|$. So this implies that $q_s = | \iota (s)|$. But this does not give us the fact that $q_s \in K$.....

Comment: Also, I think that $q_s$ is not a linear functional, due to the absolute value in its definition.

Comment: I should have written $\iota(x_k)$ not $q_{x_k}$. I have fixed this.